# Matlab access to variables in Debug Mode

Tags: matlab

Is there any possibility to get access to variables assagined to Base workspace while being in Debug Mode? Well, I am creating some variable(let`s call it var1) in other script (script1.m), then assigning it into base workspace by **assignin()** function, and now I want to Debug some function in other script(script2.m) which is using var1. Hope, I expressed it clearly.

Comment: why are you using scripts instead of functions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `dbup` to arrive at the workspace. Going back can be done with `dbdown`. `dbstack` provides information on the complete function call stack. For more info, see [Debugging](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/debugging-code.html).

Using scripts however allows you to access base-variables directly. So there is no need for `assignin()` or moving to the base workspace during debugging.